# xsd.exe generating the same enum values in multiple class files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, class, xsd

We do have more than one xsd, currently two teams are working on two different xsd along with one common xsd. If we generate separate class file for each xsd then the common xsd object types are duplicated. If we use all xsd in one command line it generate into one class file. We want separate class file for each xsd so that each team can manage separately and the future changes also can be tracked which team made the change.

Is it possible to create each class file for each xsd passed in the xsd.exe command line when multiple xsd’s are passed?

Thanks,

Zahir

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, that's not possible.

Remember that the generated class file is an output . I don't know what sort of management that would require. It is the XSD files which are the input to the process, and which should be managed.